# NSDateFormatter => how to get the range of date components?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, locale, nsdateformatter

I am facing this problem when developing a custom control for one of my apps. I have a [unicode string](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns) containing the format for dates in a specific locale. Examples for this are:

```
"M月d日 EEE ah:mm"
"a 'ga' h:mm EEE, MMM d 'lia'"
"EEE, d MMM, h:mm a"
```

I get all these string by using the **NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate method**.

I need to know the location and range of each of those elements (Hour, month, day, weekday...) But I can't find a correct way to do it.
**I basically want to divide the string into substrings depending on what they are, to reach something like this**

```
["M月", "d日", "EEE", "a", "h", "mm"]
["a", "'ga' h", "mm", "EEE", "MMM", "d 'lia'"]
["EEE", "d", "MMM", "h", "mm", "a"]
```

Is there any native way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Why can't you simply apply the localized formatting string to `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: I need to display each of those elements in different views.

Comment: I think you'll have to use a different `NSDateFormatter` for each component. Process them one at a time and build your array from the results.

Comment: Yup, tried that as well. But the format I get from individual templates for each component is different than the format I get from the group template.


In chinese for example, the hours add some strange symbol next to it.